# Benchmarkt socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, benchmarking

I want to benchmark my socket.io server. I want to test how many parallel connections and messages  the server can handle.

But my socket.io server crash after some minutes when I start the benchmark with about 200 websockets.

I tried to use the cluster module of node.js to share the process to the cores. When I use the cluster module some connections become disconnected after some time.

The server that I use for the test is a virtual server on the amazon cloud with this properties:

- 7 GB of memory
- 20 EC2 Compute Units (8 virtual cores with 2.5 EC2 Compute Units each)
- 1690 GB of instance storage
- 64-bit platform
- I/O Performance: High
- API name: c1.xlarge

Here is the code of the benchmark-client:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require("socket.io-client");
var host = "http://localhost:3000";
var timeLog = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname+'/public/time.log',{flags:'a',mode:0666,   encoding:'encoding'});
var count = 200;
var sockets = [];
var total = 0;
var countTime = 0; 
var echo = exports;
echo.start = function() {
    fs.writeFile('public/time.log',"",function(err){
        if(err) throw err;
    });

    for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
        var socket = io.connect(host,{"force new connection":true});
        sockets.push(socket);
        //console.log(i);
        socket.on("message",function(message){
            countTime++;
            time = new Date().getTime()-message;
            total+=time;
            timeLog.write(time+"\n");
            socket.send(new Date().getTime());
        });
        socket.on("disconnect",function(){
            console.log("disconnect");
        });
    }

    parallelSockets();
    var j = 0;
}

function parallelSockets(){
    for(var i = 0 ;i<count;i++){
        sockets[i].send(new Date().getTime());
    }
}
```

And here the code of the socket.io-server:

```
socket.on('message',function(message){
    start = new Date().getTime();
    socket.send(message);
    end = new Date().getTime() - start;
    logfile.write(end+"\n");
});
```

Is there any security mechanisms on socket.io that blocks so many parallel messages and connections form a client?

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What error node.js print on crash?

Comment: node.js print only on crash the word "Killed".

Comment: It might simply be because you're running out of file descriptors. Try running `ulimit -n` as the same user running node.js (if you're on Linux, at least). You can change this value using `ulimit` or, more permanently, in a config file such as `/etc/security/limits.{conf,d}`.

Comment: I'm facing with the same issue. Did you find any solution for that? I'm testing my node test on my macbook pro. I have set the u limit. but nothing has been changed. Still getting "Cannot call method 'payload' of null" after 200-250 connections.

Comment: mine crashes 1 minute or 2 minutes by error: else throw new Error('not opened'); from Websocket.js in socket.io-client module. I think something is wrong with the socket.io-client.

Answer (score 4):

I benchmarked Socket.IO and SockJS server implementations.

[Here are the results](http://mrjoes.github.com/2011/12/15/sockjs-bench.html)

[Test suite](https://github.com/mrjoes/sock-benchmarking)

Written in Java, supports 3 transports: Socket.IO 0.7+, SockJS 0.2+, raw Websockets.
There's no compiled binary, but you can get Eclipse to compile it or just use command-line javac.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have one questions. How did you make Socket.io Benchmark with 2000 WebSockets? I only can open about 1000 sockets. If i want to open more the server will be crashed or it is not available.

Comment: Make sure you increase limits like described here: http://serverfault.com/questions/48717/practical-maximum-open-file-descriptors-ulimit-n-for-a-high-volume-system

Comment: @Joes was your benchmark on 45k per second on node per core or clustered?

Edit: Nevermind: 'using single core', wow, 45k outgoing? That's crazy.  Thank you for the benchmark!!

Answer (score 3):

I didn't benchmark Socket.IO myself, but I know of 2 good resources that might help you, so check them out:

- http://drewww.github.com/socket.io-benchmarking/
- http://blog.mixu.net/2011/11/22/performance-benchmarking-socket-io-0-8-7-0-7-11-and-0-6-17-and-nodes-native-tcp/

Answer (score 0):

You may check Akinji

It opens concurrent sockets to server and listens given message and print them

http://github.com/sonsuzdongu/akinji

```
python akinji.py -c 100 --host localhost --port 3000 --waitFor 100 --on "some msg"
```